# Genericity of an induced projection map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, morse-theory, transversality, genericity

I am cross-posting a question asked on [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952798/genericity-of-an-induced-projection-map) that has not been answered, in which I am still interested in.

Let $X,Y$ be smooth manifolds, $S'$ a submanifold of $Y$, and $f:\mathbb{R}\times X\to Y$ a smooth function. Generically, we have that $f$ is transverse to $S'$, which implies that $S:=f^{-1}(S')$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}\times X$. It comes with a projection map, namely the restriction of the projection on $\mathbb{R}$ to $S$. My question is:

Is there a generic property I can also ask $f$ to check in order for this projection to be a Morse function?

So far analyzing this first transversality condition, I can describe the tangent space of $S$,
$$T_{(t,x)}S=\left\{(\dot{t},\dot{x})\in \mathbb{R}\times T_xX\,;\,(d_Xf)_{(t,x)}(\dot{x})+\dot{t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x)\in T_{f(t,x)}S'\right\},$$
and thus if $(t,x)$ is a critical point of $\pi|_S$, then every tangent vector of $S$ at $(t,x)$ is sent to $0$ by $d\pi_{(t,x)}$, which amounts to say that
$$T_{(t,x)}S=\left\{(0,\dot{x})\in \mathbb{R}\times T_xX\,;\,(d_Xf)_{(t,x)}(\dot{x})\in T_{f(t,x)}S'\right\}\simeq(d_Xf)_{(t,x)}^{-1}(T_{f(t,x)}S').$$
From this we can say that $f_t$ is not transverse to $S'$, otherwise we would have a problem of dimension ($T_{(t,x)}S$ would be 1 dimension less than expected). So by the transversality parametric theorem, I can conclude that the regular values of the projection are generic. But there is nothing about the critical values being non-degenerate, and I can even construct a counter-example where the transversality condition alone does not result in the projection being Morse: take $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(t,x)=(t,x)$ and $S'=g(\mathbb{R})$ with $g(x)=(x^3,x)$. So I have to add something else, probably a transversality condition involving the 1 or 2-jet of $f$, but I can't find it and every help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes I agree, my problem is about finding such a submanifold (I have read this book, which taught me about jets and the jet transversality theorem).

Comment: From the 1-jet of a  function $f:X\times \mathbb{R}\to Y$ transverse to $S'\subset Y$, we can check whether a point in $f^{-1}(S')$ is critical for the projection map.
However, by looking just at the 1-jet you cannot reconstruct $f^{-1}(S')$ in a neighbourhood of the critical point, and therefore you cannot check whether the critical point is non-degenerate for $pr_{\mathbb{R}}|_{f^{-1}(S')}$ by looking just at the 1-jet. 
Hopefully somebody knows a workaround to solve this issue... Good question.

Comment: http://www.projects.science.uu.nl/poisson/MorseTheoryCourse-LectureNotes(29-11).pdf on page 16 seems relevant

Comment: Thanks for the insight and for the document! @WarlockofFiretopMountain You put words on my problem, that is already of great help. I think that if I am unable to find a good submanifold in order to apply the transversality theorems stated in Thomas document, it is because of this dependency on F it should have, and so a "fixed" submanifold won't do the job.